# Can I make this javascript-based slider work in IE8/9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, slider

This is a simple javascript-based slider.

So far I got it working in updated versions of Safari (Mac), Chrome (Win), Firefox (Win) and IE11.

It does NOT work in IE8 and I believe 9 as well.

**Is that a way to fix it, so it works in IE8 and IE9?**

Code: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wkgEB)

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
<div id="slider">
    <div class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1Lc66Hp.png"></div>
    <div class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ILasdy4.png"></div>
    <div class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4CZ6tJH.png"></div>
    <div class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/qgyowEN.png"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <div id="button-previous">prev</div>
    <div id="button-next">next</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider-wrapper {width:960px; height:480px;}
#slider {width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.sp {width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;left: 100%;}
.sp.first-in {left:0;}
.sp img {width: 100%;}
#nav {margin-top:20px; width:100%;}
#button-previous {float:left;}
#button-next {float:right;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.sp').first().addClass('current').css({left: 0});

$('#button-next').click(function(){

    var old = $('.current').removeClass('current');  

    if ( old.is(':last-child')) {
        old.animate({left: "-100%"});
        $('.sp').first().css({left: "100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
    }else{
       old.animate({left: "-100%"});
       old.next().css({left: "100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
    }        

});

$('#button-previous').click(function(){

    var old = $('.current').removeClass('current');   

    if ( old.is(':first-child')) {
        old.animate({left: "100%"});
        $('.sp').last().css({left: "-100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
    }else{
        old.animate({left: "100%"});
        old.prev().css({left: "-100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
    }
});
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just checked it with IE11 emulating IE8, and aside from Codepens layout going crazy the slider seems to work just fine. Can you be more specific as to what is not working?

Comment: @FlorianHaider I've got IE8 opened in front of me and it does not work. The images don't load. Have a look [here](http://i.imgur.com/wNYbF0u.jpg)

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is: close your img tags correctly like `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1Lc66Hp.png" />`, older IEs tend to be very strict about this. Also I just checked one of your image files, those are not actual PNGs but base64 data urls inside a PNG. IE8 does only support data urls with a size less than 32KB, so try using real PNG files.